# "Master" view in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I want to create Master/Base view for my SenchaTouch2 application. It should have header, footer and content zone. Header and footer are static, but content should be declared in concrete view.
I can't find solution for my problem in sencha docs. Maybe it's a wrong way? Any link to sencha guides would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this type of functionality you can use navigation view or create any one view with card layout and put two item  with docked top and bottom which you want to fix and third itam change as per you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a view that extend from Container or Panel with 3 items. You decide which xtype (panel, container, toolbar, etc.) is your header and footer and you should use the card layout and dock at the top or button: docked  : 'top'
Then you can use the 3rd element and update the view according to your needs and using the model and controller as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Define a new Ext.Container class with header and footer containers. And then create new instances of it and insert the content view. Something like this:

```
Ext.define('App.view.BaseView', {
    extend : 'Ext.Container',
    xtype : 'masterview',
    config : {
         items : [{
         xtype : 'container',
         height : 100,
         html : 'This is header',
         styleHtmlContent : true,
         // docked : 'top'      //if needed
       }, {
         xtype : 'container',
         height : 100,
         html : 'This is footer',
         styleHtmlContent : true,
         // docked : 'bottom'      //if needed
       }]
    }
});
```

And use it like this:

```
var panel = Ext.create('App.view.BaseView');
panel.insert(1, {
    xtype : 'container',
    html : 'This is concrete view'
});
```

This is the most basic example. You can tweak it the way you want.